# How to setup HTTPS on a GKE FastAPI api

Tags: kubernetes, https, google-kubernetes-engine, fastapi, uvicorn

I've been trying to deploy a small API using FastAPI(and uvicorn to serve) framework on GKE.
I made a deployment and an associated service that are working well but I have trouble understanding how https should be implemented.

Is it internal to FastAPI? Or is it on GKE's side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's more depends on the requirement you are looking for.

**Option 1** : HTTPS termination at LB level

If you are using the **LB** with the **GKE** and don't want **End to end** **HTTPS** connection you can add the **SSL/TLS** cert at Load balancer level **GKE** and terminate SSL and backend it will be HTTP.

**Option 2** : End to end encryption with HTTPS

If you want the End to end encryption with **HTTPS** you have to add the certificate with Code and the application will use that cert.

In both cases, you create the self-signed(not good option) certificate and use it.

If you don't want to use **self-signed** certificate, you can use the GCP [cert-manager](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/overview) to create/use the certificates.

here is the tutorial with steps to use the managed certificates with **GKE** : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs

Comment: I've tried the first option and followed the great tutorial you posted. I've managed to make the ingress and certificate manager.
However in the ingress, when clicking on the TLS certificate I see this Domain
 
Status
[my domain name]  
FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE
I can access the ingress ip over http but not https yet, any ides?

Comment: You can not create the ssl certificate for IP, if you are using ip it would be hard with https. Map your ingress IP to domain and create ssl certificate to that domain attach certificate to ingress and check https.